# how to count the total number of checked data grid view check boxes by rows not by columns

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewrow

We are currently doing a student monitoring attendance , and we want to count the total number of days each student is present and absent .

```
     Subject LN  FN    MI  05/21/14   05/20/14   05/21/14 05/22/14  05/23/14  P  A

     Comp101 Yu Erick   C   (checked|(unchecked)|(checked)|(checked)|(checked)|4 | 1
```

"This is what we wanted to do but instead of counting horizontally it counts vertically.Is there anyone who can help us solving this problem?

Comment: we cant tell you what is wrong with your code without seeing....your code. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23728412/edit) your post to show what you have tried. and how did [the answer last time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23668834/1070452) not work?

Comment: Is the Checked and Unchecked is a DataGridView CheckBox or just a String Value ?

Comment: @Goroundo , It is a DataGridView checkBox

Comment: Ohhh okay, i post the answer for that. try it i hope it helps

Comment: @GoroundoVipa , We edited our datagridview and we tried your code.But an error appeared , "Conversion from string "Yu" to type 'Boolean' is not valid."

Comment: Hmmm... it means that the Cell range is lost in condition to boolean, like the condition goes to the DataGridViewTextBox, can you explain your datagridview format like: first Col is DataGridViewTextBox, second to Sixth is DataGridViewCheckBox Then seventh is DataGridViewTextBox.

Comment: @GoroundoVipa, Our first five column are DataGridViewTextBox and followed by eleven Columns of DatagridviewCheckBox .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button1.Click
Dim Present As Integer = 0
Dim Absent As Integer = 0
For a = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    For b = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 8
        If DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(b + 5).Value = True Then
            Present += 1
        Else
            Absent += 1
        End If
    Next
    DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(10).Value =  Present 
    DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(11).Value =  Absent
    Present = 0
    Absent = 0
Next
End Sub
```

Try This ....

Comment: Thank you very much !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It worked !  You've been a great help !  Gracias !

Comment: Hi !! Do you know how to transfer data from textbox to the header of dgvcheckbox?  Sorry for disturbing you once again .   I hope you can help us with this .  Thank You ! :))

Comment: Not enough reputation left =D

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: It's like i haven't answer your first question because you didn't recognize it as an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks, if you have a problem don't shy to ask, thanks again... =D

Comment: Actually we do have a problem, our problem is that we do not know how to transfer the value inputted in the textbox to the dgvcheckbox header . .

Comment: please help us again . .thank you very much :). im sorry for disturbing you again and again. .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773304/how-can-we-transfer-the-value-of-a-textboxes-into-the-header-of-a-dvgcheckboxes . . here's the link thank you very much again

Comment: we have another problem . this the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863550/how-to-save-a-check-and-unchecked-checkboxes-from-datagridview-to-the-database-u . I hope someone can help us .  AGAIN . :)

Comment: we have another problem .  heres the link . : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879919/how-to-save-the-header-of-the-datagridview-in-database-using-vb-net  .  Can someone help us ???  Thank you .  :))  .  :D

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is what you want...

[image]

This Code Actually Check every Cell that contains Checkbox Or DatePresented

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For a = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        For b = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 2
            If DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(b + 1).Value = True Then
                count += 1
            End If
        Next
        DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(6).Value = count
        count = 0
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For a = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        For b = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 6
            If DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(b + 5).Value = True Then
                count += 1
            End If
        Next
        DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(4).Value = count
        count = 0
    Next
End Sub
```

Leave the Attendance Column Blank cause the Total will be insert there...

Wew, I Think it solves your Problem =D

Comment: Thank You ! It worked . :) . Our only problem is how to count the unchecked checkboxes  . Can you help us ? :) . Thank you once again .

Comment: :| I Already answered the first question but theres another follow up question hmmm... anyway let see,

Comment: I'm sorry for disturbing you , But please help us because we're having a little trouble in solving this problem . We're  just new in using vb.net and we're just a student . Thank you very much for helping us.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim Present As Integer = 0
Dim Absent As Integer = 0
For a = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    For b = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 6
        If DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(b + 5).Value = True Then
            Present += 1
        Else
            Absent += 1
        End If
    Next
    DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(4).Value = "Present: " & Present & " Absent: " & Absent
    Present = 0
    Absent = 0
Next
End Sub
```

Okay Here it is all done...

Comment: Thank you .  But something went wrong , once we click the button for calculating the unchecked checkboxes, 13 appeared in our cell  instead of 10 only . Can you tell us what's wrong ?

Comment: I Can't visualize your DataGridView, Can you post some picture so i can construct the code.

Comment: We can't post a picture.

Comment: Can you tell us how can we change the column count that appeared in our cell ?

Comment: I bit confuse about your datagridview first 5 is DGVTextBox and (Eleven DGVCheckBox ?) which means that you have a total of 5+11 = 16 Columns but you want to display the present in 11 and absent in 12 hmmm.... can you be more specific

Comment: We just have eleven DataGridViewCheckBoxes but what appeared in our cell for the absents is fourteen.

Comment: Sorry .  Our first five Column is DGVTextbox followed by 11 DGVCheckboxes . Then folowed once again by 2 DGVTextbox . 5 + 11 + 2 = 18 .  We have 18 Columns and we want to display the present in the 17th and absent on the 18th .