# How can we transfer the value of a textboxes into the header of a dvgcheckboxes?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

We wanted to let the user to input a value which is the date when the instructor/user check his/her class attendance and then once the button is clicked the value inputted in the textbox will be transfer in the header of a dgvcheckbox. So please help us solve this problem . . we've been trying to solved this but unfortunately we can't. So I hope that you could all help us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

[image]

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: We tried to use your code,,but there's an error : "ColumnCount Property cannot be set on a Data-bound DataGridView Control."

Comment: And we can't click the checkboxes in our datagridview.

Comment: Ohhhh... !! Okay your DataGridVIew Is occupied by DataBind, w8 i see my other codes for that,

Comment: Ok .  Thank you .  We'll wait for that. :)

Comment: At this point it's hard to edit a DataGridView that has been occupied by a DataBind, my solution for that is to reBind the DataGridView with new Column Names.

Comment: Can you tell us how ? Thank You .

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button2.Click
'----------------Clear Recent Data on DataGridView-------------------
Try
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
Try
DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
'----------------Display Again Record In DataGridView-----------------------
clsTR.displayTestResults(DataGridView1, "SELECT STUDENT_NAME AS [Student Name],MONDAY AS TextBox1.Text WHERE Something something")
End Sub
End Class
```

WHERE STUDENT_NAME and MONDAY is the name of the database Column
using "AS" will replace the database column STUDENT_NAME AS [Student Name]

Comment: i forgot remove the "DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5"