# How to save a check and unchecked checkboxes from datagridview to the database using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

```
   Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        myconnection.Open()
        'Declaration of Variables
        Dim str As String

        Dim vCourseCode As String
        Dim vSection As String
        Dim vSurname As String
        Dim vFirstName As String
        Dim vMiddleInitial As String
        Dim vDate1 As Boolean
        Dim vDate2 As Boolean
        Dim vDate3 As Boolean
        Dim vDate4 As Boolean
        Dim vDate5 As Boolean
        Dim vDate6 As Boolean
        Dim vDate7 As Boolean
        Dim vDate8 As Boolean
        Dim vDate9 As Boolean
        Dim vAbsent As String
        Dim vPresent As String
        Dim vEQ As String


        For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
            vCourseCode = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
            vSection = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value
            vSurname = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
            vFirstName = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value
            vMiddleInitial = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(5).Value 
            vAbsent = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(6).Value
            vPresent = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value
            vEQ = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(8).Value
            vDate1 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
            vDate2 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
            vDate3 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value
            vDate4 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
            vDate5 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value
            vDate6 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(5).Value
            vDate7 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(6).Value
            vDate8 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value
            vDate9 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(8).Value

            str = "Insert into StudentsAttendance ([CourseCode],[Section],[Surname],[FirstName],[MiddleName],[Date1],[Date2],[Date3],[Date4],[Date5],[Date6],[Date7],[Date8],[Date9],[Absent],[Present],[EQ]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"


            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseCode", vCourseCode)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", vSection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", vSurname)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", vFirstName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", vMiddleInitial)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", vDate1)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", vDate2)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date3", vDate3)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date4", vDate4)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date5", vDate5)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date6", vDate6)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date7", vDate7)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date8", vDate8)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date9", vDate9)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Absent", vAbsent)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Present", vPresent)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EQ", vEQ)

        Next

        myconnection.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully!", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "oledb Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the code we use to save the checked/unchecked checkboxes in the database. Unfortunately, it didn't work! but when we used this to the other part of the program it worked! so were a little bit confuse on why it didn't work on the part of the program where we put this code . can anyone help us? thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Juri, i notice that you need my help again =D, okay okay what is the message or the error popups up when you run this code ?

Comment: Theres no error .  It just that when we run the program and we clicked the save button,  a messagebox will apppear and it said "Save SuccessFully !"  .  But when we checked our database we saw nothing .

Answer (score 0):

```
   Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        myconnection.Open()
        'Declaration of Variables
        Dim str As String

        Dim vCourseCode As String
        Dim vSection As String
        Dim vSurname As String
        Dim vFirstName As String
        Dim vMiddleInitial As String
        Dim vDate1 As Boolean
        Dim vDate2 As Boolean
        Dim vDate3 As Boolean
        Dim vDate4 As Boolean
        Dim vDate5 As Boolean
        Dim vDate6 As Boolean
        Dim vDate7 As Boolean
        Dim vDate8 As Boolean
        Dim vDate9 As Boolean
        Dim vAbsent As String
        Dim vPresent As String
        Dim vEQ As String


        For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
            vCourseCode = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
            vSection = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value
            vSurname = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
            vFirstName = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value
            vMiddleInitial = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(5).Value 
            vAbsent = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(6).Value
            vPresent = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value
            vEQ = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(8).Value
            vDate1 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
            vDate2 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
            vDate3 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value
            vDate4 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value
            vDate5 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value
            vDate6 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(5).Value
            vDate7 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(6).Value
            vDate8 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(7).Value
            vDate9 = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(8).Value

            str = "Insert into StudentsAttendance ([CourseCode],[Section],[Surname],[FirstName],[MiddleName],[Date1],[Date2],[Date3],[Date4],[Date5],[Date6],[Date7],[Date8],[Date9],[Absent],[Present],[EQ]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"


            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myconnection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseCode", vCourseCode)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", vSection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", vSurname)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", vFirstName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", vMiddleInitial)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", vDate1)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", vDate2)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date3", vDate3)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date4", vDate4)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date5", vDate5)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date6", vDate6)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date7", vDate7)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date8", vDate8)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date9", vDate9)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Absent", vAbsent)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Present", vPresent)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EQ", vEQ)
            '==========PUT A cmd EXECUTION here so all your data will insert==========
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            '=========================================================================
        Next

        myconnection.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully!", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Catch ex As OleDb.OleDbException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "oledb Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try
    End Sub
```

Try this i think that is missing to execute...

Comment: Yeah ,  Your right .  :) Thank you once again .  :D .  Salamat po .  :))

Comment: No problem i'm happy to help you =D