# How to save the header of the datagridview in database using vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, datagridview

We wanted to save the header of a datagridview in the database. The header of the datagridview is the value we inputted in the textbox .What we want is to save the header as the field of our database . Does anyone know how to do it ??thank you

Comment: What do you mean save DataGridViewHeader ?, in what senario ?

Comment: We want to save the header of our dgv as the field of our database . Our dgv header is the text we inputted in our textbox . Is it possible to happen .  Or can you help us in this case ?  Thank You]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... Like This one ?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim fetchDGVHeaders(DataGridView1.ColumnCount) As String
    For a = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        fetchDGVHeaders(a) = DataGridView1.Columns(a).Name
        MsgBox(fetchDGVHeaders(a))
    Next
    INSERT_INTO_DB("INSERT INTO DBHeaders(MEaw,MEow,MEow_MEow)VALUES('" & fetchDGVHeaders(0) & "','" & fetchDGVHeaders(1) & "','" & fetchDGVHeaders(2) & "','" & fetchDGVHeaders(3) & "')")
End Sub
```

Fetch the current DataGridView Headers then store it to other table

Comment: Thank you .  we'll try this out tomorrow .  :)

Comment: Okay lang po .  Salamat po ulet :)

Comment: We encounter an error it said "INSERT_INTO_DB" is not declared blah blah . .We also try to change DB from "INSERT_INTO_DB", to the name of our database but still the error shows up! . .Can you tell us what is the problem with the code? We just copy your code and change the name of the database.

Comment: INSERT_INTO_DB is just a sample that you will change based on your implementation in insert function in Database,

Comment: We don't get it .  We haven't still save it .  And we don't know why .  :(

Comment: I mean, Create kayo ng isa pang table para store ung mga DataGridViewHeaders nyo tapos kapag ni run nyo yung program nyo i fetch nyo nalang yung mga DataGridViewHeaders na gusto nyo i display sa DataGridView... =D

Comment: ok! thank you ..tanong lang po namin kung ung meow meow na nilagay nyo e fields sa database?

Comment: Jhenn Naman nag jojowk =D, ung meow meow sample koh langyun sa database fields, parang kung ung total column nyo sa DataGridView nyo ay 22 dapat kapag kumawa kayo ng table para pag store ng DGVHeaders >= 22 fields, para kapag nakapag lagay na kayo ng DGVHeaders doon i fetch nyo nalang un data para yun ang mag rerename sa DGV nyo kapag na display =D

Comment: ganito po kasi ginawa namin .                      Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim str As String
        Dim fetchDGVHeaders(DataGridView1.ColumnCount) As String
        For a = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            fetchDGVHeaders(a) = DataGridView1.Columns(a).Name
            MsgBox("Ewan")
        Next


        str = "INSERT INTO JuliangBaliw(Date1,Date2,Date3)VALUES('" & fetchDGVHeaders(0) & "','" & fetchDGVHeaders(1) & "','" & fetchDGVHeaders(2) & "','" & fetchDGVHeaders(3) & "')"
    End Sub

Comment: Yan tama yan pero parang sobra yung sa Values sa DBFields kc (Date1,Date2,Date3)VALUES('" & fetchDGVHeaders(0) hanggang 3

Comment: Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim str As String
        Dim fetchDGVHeaders(DataGridView1.ColumnCount) As String
        For a = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            fetchDGVHeaders(a) = DataGridView1.Columns(a).Name
            MsgBox("Baliw si Julia")
        Next


        str = "INSERT INTO JuliangBaliw(Date1,Date2,Date3,Date4)VALUES('" & fetchDGVHeaders(0) & "','" & fetchDGVHeaders(1) & "','" & fetchDGVHeaders(2) & "','" & fetchDGVHeaders(3) & "')"
    End Sub

Comment: 18 po yung columns namin.  yung first 6 columns ay dgvtextboxes then yung sumunod na 9 columns ay dgvcheckboxes then yung 3 columns ay dgvtextboxes ulet .  Ang gusto lang po naming isave na header ay yung sa dgvcheckboxes .

Comment: apat lang muna yung nilagay namin for example lang

Comment: Basta i save nyo sa ibang Table ng database yung nakuha nyong DataGridViewHeader Names tapos kapag ka load ng DataGridView nyo i lagay nyo nalang ung column name nya bawat isa...